# How to switch between 2 javascript files

Tags: javascript

I just wonder if it possible to change/ switch between 2 javascript files in a web page ?
If user choose the EN language from my site then the file alljavaforEN.js will be activated.
But
If user choose the FR language from my site then the file alljavaforFR.js will be activated

I´m so sorry if my question is too simple. But I have been search in google I have not found any tutrials. Possibly I use wrong keywords ?

However what I did here is

```
<html>
<head>

Function changeLanguage (lang) {
if (lang=="fr"){///Do something to activate this <script type="text/javascript" src="alljavaforFR.js"></script>}

if (lang=="en"){ //Do something to activate this <script type="text/javascript" src="alljavaforEN.js"></script>}

}
</head>
<body>
  <a href="#" onclick="changeLanguage('en');"> Change to English</a>
  <a href="#" onclick="changeLanguage('fr');"> Change to French</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of ugly... but.

```
if (lang=="fr"){
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="alljavaforFR.js"></script>')
}

if (lang=="en"){ 
    document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="alljavaforEN.js"></script>')
}
```

Alternatively a better approach might be (not when the page is loading) to load the script in a deferred way, something like.

```
function loadScript(src){
    var el = document.createElement("script");
    el.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

And then:

```
if (lang === "fr"){
    loadScript("alljavaforFR.js")
} else  if (lang === "en"){
    loadScript("alljavaforEN.js");
}
```

(You can wrap it in a function)

Comment: I will try this now. But before anything, does this script work with every browsers ?

Comment: @user3104858 yes, it does. Note that `changeLanguage` won't work like you expect since once a script is loaded it's loaded _for good_ though. The code at the top is only intended to execute _once_ and before the page has loaded. You might want to look into templating and how internationalization is usually done, it's not by including scripts over and over :)

Comment: Anyway this is the good beginning !! thanks I´ll give you credit within  a few min. Since my account was created just now.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" id="script" src="alljavaforFR.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function changeLanguage(lang) {
  var src;
  switch(lang) {
    case "en":
    src = "alljavaforEN.js";
    break;
    case "fr":
    default:
    src = "alljavaforFR.js";
  }
  document.getElementById("script").src = src;
}
</script>


<a href="#" onclick="changeLanguage('en');"> Change to English</a>
<a href="#" onclick="changeLanguage('fr');"> Change to French</a>
```