# How to Switch Between Javascript Files

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to set up a leaflet map where the user can choose between two expressions of a dataset. The first is a heatmap and the second proportional symbols, with each set up in its own .js. I'm trying to work off of this example: [How to switch between 2 javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597066/how-to-switch-between-2-javascript-files)

I have the following code, which doesn't seem to be throwing any errors, but also doesn't seem to be accomplishing what I want it to. I'm not understanding how to link the html div to the javascript function. Does anyone have any insights?

html:

```
<div id ="expression">
    <h4>Choose your expression</h4>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeExpression('heat');">Heatmap</a>
    <a href="#" onclick="changeExpression('prop');">Prop symbols</a>
</div>
```

js:

```
function changeExpression(src){
    var heat = document.createElement("script");
    heat.src = main_heat.js;
    document.body.appendChild(heat);
    var prop = document.createElement("script");
    prop.src = main.js;
    document.body.appendChild(prop);

    if (expression === "heat"){
        loadScript("main_heat.js")
    } else if (expression === "prop"){
        loadScript("main.js");
    }
};
```

revised main.js:

```
function changeExpression(src){
    var heat = document.createElement("script");
    heat.src = "js/main_heat.js";
    document.body.appendChild(heat);
    var prop = document.createElement("script");
    prop.src = "js/main.js";
    document.body.appendChild(prop);

/*  if (src === "heat"){
        loadScript("main_heat.js")
    } else if (src === "prop"){
        loadScript("main.js");
    } */

    if (expression === "heat"){
    loadScript("data/main_heat.js")
    } else if (expression == "prop"){
    loadScript("data/main.js");
    }
    function loadScript(src){
        var el = document.createElement("script");
        el.src = src;
        document.body.appendChild(el);
    }
};
```

Comment: So if `LoadScript` is appending the name of the js file as a source to a script tag, if you check the html of the page afterwards, is that script tag present?

Comment: Also you have lines like `heat.src = main_heat.js;` which isnt valid javascript, since `main_heat.js` is not a string. Check your console for errors.

Comment: is ```loadScript()``` function implemented anywhere in your code?

Comment: Good catch with loadScript, thanks! I've added the suggested changes, but haven't gotten the code to successfully switch between the files. I'll post the changes to the original question to see if there's something I'm missing

Answer (score 0):

The function `loadScript()` doesn't seem to be defined in your code.

This should do:

```
if (expression === "heat"){
    loadScript("/path/to/main_heat.js")
} else if (expression === "prop"){
    loadScript("/path/to/main.js");
}


function loadScript(src){
    var el = document.createElement("script");
    el.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Just make sure you're passing a valid path when your calling your function (ie. replace `/path/to/main_heat.js` as appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

You will need two functions defined as below with correct variable names.

chnageExpression as below:

```
function changeExpression(src){
    if(src === "heat"){
      loadScript("main_heat.js")
    } else if(src === "prop"){
      loadScript("main.js")
    }
 }
```

loadScript as below:

```
function loadScript(src){
    var el = document.createElement("script");
    el.src = src;
    document.body.appendChild(el);
}
```

Hope this will clear confusion between different functions and variable names.